Trying to save "reviews" in hive. Is there a way to convert data to binary inline?
Rating and combination is an unknown type for hive.
I'm trying to avoid classes (though it's fine, anything that makes this work...). I just want to save the progress, and at start loading it back.
import 'package:dolphinsr_dart/dolphinsr_dart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart' as pathProvider;
import 'dart:convert';

var reviewMap = {};

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Directory directory = await pathProvider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);

  var box = await Hive.openBox('testBox');

  final reviews = <Review>[];
  final dolphin = DolphinSR();

  dolphin.addMasters(<Master>[
    Master(id: '1', fields: <String>[
      'คน',
      'person'
    ], combinations: <Combination>[
      Combination(front: <int>[0], back: <int>[1]),
      Combination(front: <int>[1], back: <int>[0]),
    ]),
    Master(id: '2', fields: <String>[
      'คบ',
      'To date'
    ], combinations: <Combination>[
      Combination(front: <int>[0], back: <int>[1]),
      Combination(front: <int>[1], back: <int>[0]),
    ])
  ]);
  dolphin.addReviews(reviews);

  var stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 2, overdue: 0 }

  printStats(stats);

  var card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  var review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  reviewMap = {
    'master': review.master,
    'combination': review.combination,
    'ts': review.ts,
    'rating': review.rating
  };
  print(reviewMap);
  await box.add(reviewMap);
  print(box.getAt(0));

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);

  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);
}

void printCard(DRCard card) {
  print(
      '${card.master}-${card.back}-${card.front}-${card.combination!.back}-${card.combination!.front} - ${card.lastReviewed} - ${card.dueDate}');
}

void printStats(stats) {
  print('${stats.due}-${stats.later}-${stats.learning}-${stats.overdue}');
}


Is there a way to convert them to binary inline?
I have found this BinaryWriter class: https://pub.dev/documentation/hive/latest/hive/BinaryWriter-class.html
But I don't know how to use it or even if it is suitable for me?

import 'package:dolphinsr_dart/dolphinsr_dart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'dart:io';
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

var reviewMap = {};
var reviewMapStored = {};
// var review = [];

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  var box = await Hive.openBox('testBox');

  final reviews = <Review>[];
  final dolphin = DolphinSR();

  dolphin.addMasters(<Master>[
    Master(id: '1', fields: <String>[
      'คน',
      'person'
    ], combinations: <Combination>[
      Combination(front: <int>[0], back: <int>[1]),
      Combination(front: <int>[1], back: <int>[0]),
    ]),
    Master(id: '2', fields: <String>[
      'คบ',
      'To date'
    ], combinations: <Combination>[
      Combination(front: <int>[0], back: <int>[1]),
      Combination(front: <int>[1], back: <int>[0]),
    ])
  ]);

  print(box.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
    reviewMapStored = box.getAt(i);
    print(box.getAt(i));
    reviewMap['master'] = reviewMapStored['master'];
    reviewMap['ts'] = reviewMapStored['ts'];
    if (reviewMapStored['combination'] == 'Combination([1]-[0])') {
      reviewMap['combination'] = Combination(front: <int>[1], back: <int>[0]);
    } else {
      reviewMap['combination'] = Combination(front: <int>[0], back: <int>[1]);
    }
    if (reviewMapStored['rating'] == 'Rating.Hard') {
      reviewMap['rating'] = Rating.Hard;
    } else if (reviewMapStored['rating'] == 'Rating.Good') {
      reviewMap['rating'] = Rating.Good;
    } else if (reviewMapStored['rating'] == 'Rating.Easy') {
      reviewMap['rating'] = Rating.Easy;
    } else {
      reviewMap['rating'] = Rating.Again;
    }

    var review = Review(
        master: reviewMap['master'],
        combination: reviewMap['combination'],
        ts: reviewMap['ts'],
        rating: reviewMap['rating']);
    dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

    // review = reviewMap;
    // dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);
  }
  // print(reviewMapStored);
  // print(reviewMap);

  dolphin.addReviews(reviews);

  var stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 2, overdue: 0 }

  printStats(stats);

  var card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  var review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  reviewMap = {
    'master': review.master,
    'combination': review.combination.toString(),
    'ts': review.ts,
    'rating': review.rating.toString()
  };
  await box.add(reviewMap);
  // print(box.getAt(0));
  // print(box.values);

  review = Review(
      master: reviewMap['master'],
      combination: Combination(front: <int>[0], back: <int>[1]),
      ts: reviewMap['ts'],
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);

  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Hard);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Easy);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Easy);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Easy);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);

  card = dolphin.nextCard()!;
  printCard(card);
  review = Review(
      master: card.master,
      combination: card.combination,
      ts: DateTime.now(),
      rating: Rating.Easy);
  dolphin.addReviews(<Review>[review]);

  stats =
      dolphin.summary(); // => { due: 0, later: 0, learning: 10, overdue: 0 }
  printStats(stats);
}

void printCard(DRCard card) {
  print(
      '${card.master}-${card.back}-${card.front}-${card.combination!.back}-${card.combination!.front} - ${card.lastReviewed} - ${card.dueDate}');
}

void printStats(stats) {
  print('${stats.due}-${stats.later}-${stats.learning}-${stats.overdue}');
}


